# SQL convert column into

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below  in SQL Server 2010

[image: input data]

But I need an output like below

[image: desired result]

Please help me to solve, I need a select statement like how we are using pivot in Excel.

Comment: Please read and follow this: [How to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how about not doing this in SQL, but in your excel file. And please help *us* by not attaching images as example, but text

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot table as :

```
SELECT [ID], [Data1] AS [Type1], [Data2] AS [Type2], [Data3] AS [Type3], [Data4] AS [Type4]
FROM (
    SELECT [ID], [Type], [Data]
    FROM table1
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX([Data])
    FOR [Type] IN ([Data1], [Data2], [Data3], [Data4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

I hope this will help you!!

Comment: They are trying to aggregate three columns. The pivot syntax only allows for one